# Как в многопотоке качать один файл

Tags: c#

Есть файл размером 1 гигабайт на удаленном сервере. Как с помощью `Task.Parallel` поделить файл на `сhunk` и скачивать их как это делает `Download Master`?

Ниже пример однопоточного скачивания

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://xxx.txt");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(@"xxx.txt"))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            DateTime nowTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if ((nowTime - startTime).TotalMinutes > 5)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(
                    "Download timed out");
            }
            bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324529/http-range-bytes-with-webclient-c-sharp Но надо убедиться, что сервер поддерживает такой заголовок

Comment: `WebRequest` устарел. Используйте `HttpClient` вместо него.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в чём дело. Если вы только читаете файл, то из него можно читать сразу из нескольких потоков, т. к. не идёт изменение содержимого. Для того, чтобы разные потоки могли получать доступ к файлу, нужно дать им разрешение с помощью `FileShare`:

```
static void Main()
{
    const string targetPath = "target.txt";
    const int chunkSize = 32;

    using var client = new HttpClient();
    using var response = client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com/").Result;
    using var source = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    using var target = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, 4096, true);
    target.SetLength(source.Length);
    var tasks = new Task[GetChunkCount(source.Length, chunkSize)];

    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        tasks[i] = CopyChunkAsync(source, target, i, chunkSize);

    Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
static long GetChunkCount(long length, long chunkSize)
{
    // checks skipped

    var rem = length % chunkSize;
    var div = length / chunkSize;

    return rem == 0 ? div : div + 1;
}
static async Task CopyChunkAsync(Stream source, Stream target, int chunkIndex, int chunkSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // checks skipped

    var offset = chunkIndex * chunkSize;
    var bytesLeft = source.Length - offset;
    var len = (int)Math.Min(chunkSize, bytesLeft);
    using var bufOwner = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(len);
    var buf = bufOwner.Memory[..len];

    source.Position = offset;
    var readedBytes = await source.ReadAsync(buf, cancellationToken);

    if (readedBytes != len) { Console.WriteLine("err"); }

    target.Position = offset;
    await target.WriteAsync(buf, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Это всё хорошо, но у автора вопрос в том, как сделать http-запрос на многопоточное скачивание.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov исправил

Comment: Да нет же. Речь идёт об HTTP-заголовке Range.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если использовать `Range`, то нам потребуется `GetChunkCount(source.Length)` запросов в ресурсу. Тут про скачивание *всего* ресурса, а не про скачивание его *куска*